# Rebol 3 - How to create a password text field? (circles or stars instead of text)

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

In Rebol 2, in order to create a password text field it is possible to write

```
view [
    field hide
]
```

How to do it in Rebol 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hide-input` facet of text input widgets to control whether input is shown or not.

There are two ways how to do this. First, you can override the facet directly in your layout specification:

```
view [field options [hide-input: true]]
```

Second, you can create a custom widget (let's call it `password`) derived from `field` but overriding the `hide-input` facet:

```
stylize [
    password: field [         ;; Create a PASSWORD widget, derived from FIELD.
        facets: [             ;; Override FIELD's facets.
            hide-input: true  ;; Mask the input with asterisks.
        ]
    ]
]

view [password]
```

I hope that a `password` widget will eventually come bundled with stock R3-GUI.